# AEM 6.5, SPA, Angular 9 - How do I subscribe to a parent container component from a child component?

Tags: angular, typescript, single-page-application, aem, adobe-exprience-manager

AEM 6.5, SPA, Angular 9

In the editor and published page via Typescript, I'd like to subscribe to a parent container component from a child component.  If I drag a parent container component on the editor page and then drag a child component so it is inside of the parent container, how can the child get a reference to its closest parent so it can subscribe to the parent's changes?

When a component is dragged onto the editor page, are there certain Angular-monitored events that are triggered and would help with a solution?

Two use cases I'm trying to solve:

1. The parent container has a background color property that is also the background color of any child component. The child needs to know what its closest parent's background color is so it can use the appropriate text color.
2. To dynamically build a backend data structure, the child needs to know the ID of its closest parent component.